# Merge two rasters with different resolution

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, merge

I'm a student and pretty much new with Qgis.

I'm trying to merge two elevation rasters. They have different resolution (one is a 5mx5m DTM and the other is a 1mx1m DTM) and different extension.

[image]

I've clipped the two rasters out of two bigger rasters using Clip with mask.

I've tried to resample the lower resolution raster using gal.warp(reproject) but the all system crashes down every time.

Is there a solution or maybe another way to merge them?

Here are the parameters I run the algorithm with:

[image]

I also tried to merge them with no resampling using gdal_merge with senseless results. Here's the gdal_merge parameters:

### Heading ##[image]

Comment: Resampling may have troubles with compressing the whole output as a single block. Try without compression, or by creating a tiled tiff by adding `-co TILED=YES`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at gdal_merge (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html). It's a python command so your gdal instance will need have been compiled with python support. It can handle differing resolutions (I believe the output resolution is taken from the first input raster) as long as all input sources are in the same projection. I don't know why gdalwarp is failing on your system but perhaps this is an alternative.

Comment: I've already tried gdal_merge but the result is a much bigger no values raster :/

Comment: How did your gdal_merge command look like? Are your both source files in EPSG:32632?

Comment: Yes both file are in EPSG:32632.

Comment: Try saving the output to a file and not a temporary file. I have had issues with processes failing in the past where large outputs to temp files crash.

Comment: Great! Saving the output to a file worked! But unfortunately I still can't merge the two 1x1 DTMs :/

Comment: What is the extent of each separate raster you are trying to merge? (In your terminal you can just run gdalinfo 'your  raster' or select raster info in qgis)

Comment: At the end I succeeded in merging the two rasters (after resampling the 1x1 to 5x5) using GRASS r.patch. Thank you anyway for the advice ;)